# Android packageReleaseError: duplicate files during packaging of APK

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I checked the other answers, but it still doesn't seem to work for me. The problem is that gradle is complaining about having duplicate files, and the suggested exclude does not work

here's the trace:

```
:app:packageReleaseError: duplicate files during packaging of APK /home/ubuntu/libprojectB/androidSample/MyTestApp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease    Path in archive: lib/armeabi-v7a/libprojectA.so
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease    Origin 1: /home/ubuntu/libprojectB/androidSample/MyTestApp/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libprojectA.so
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease    Origin 2: /home/ubuntu/libprojectB/androidSample/MyTestApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.snapchat/libprojectB/0.3.52.1/jni/armeabi-v7a/libprojectA.so
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageReleaseYou can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease    android {
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease      packagingOptions {
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libprojectA.so'
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease      }
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease    }
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease
> Building 96% > :app:packageRelease:app:packageRelease
```

But even if i do add that `packagingOption`, it still complains of the issue. What am i doing wrong?

Basically my project set up is that i have `projectA` compiled into a `*.so` file, and i try to use that `projectA` native file in `projectB`, but `projectB` also compiles into a `*.so` file.